# How to resolve jailshell install error

Tags: linux, makefile, installation, linux-mint, jail-shell

I'm trying to install `jailshell` but while using `make` command, I am getting the following error:

> /bin/sh: PYTHONINTERPRETER@: command not found make[1]: ***
>   [jk_lib.pyc] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   /root/soft/jailkit-2.13/py' make: *** [all] Error 2

How can i resolve this error?